# PHP traits conflict

Tags: php, traits

Imagine that I have two traits, `data` and `events`. The trait `data` exposes public method `data()` and use `events` trait. The trait `events` just exposes method `trigger()`. Basically that:

```
trait events {
    public function trigger($value) { echo "Event: {$value}\n"; }
}

trait data {
    use events;

    public function data($key, $value) {
        $this->trigger("changed {$key}");
    }
}
```

Now I need two things (cases): use trait `data` on my class `user`, but *without* allow access trait `events` directly:

```
class user {
    use data;

    public function set_name($name) {
        $this->data("name", "John Doe");
    }
}
```

And the second case is other class called `config` that need uses `data` and `events`. Like:

```
class config {
    use data, events;

    public function set_config($key, $value) {
        $this->data($key, $value);
        $this->trigger("reconfig");
    }
}
```

The problem is that:

> **Fatal error**: Trait method `event` has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on `set_config`...

**My question is**: can I include trait "privately" if I want? Something like `private use events` on `data` trait.

Comment: To solve your error just change `use data, events;` to `use events;`

Comment: Private/exclusive `events` traits to `data` trait if class don't uses that. So if I don't do `use events` on class, I should not have access to the method `trigger()`.

Comment: You don't need to use traits. You need to use delegation.